# Custom message in Outlook message

Tags: vba, outlook

In Outlook 2003 (and probably later), when you receive a mailitem and reply to it, it will display a message in the original item below the sender. Translated from Dutch it should be something like "You replied on 21-02-2012 13:37".

I would like to show a custom message there. Is that possible?

Comment: I really don't think so. This is a builtin feature of Outlook and I can't see how we could alter it with VBA.

Comment: It is possible, i've seen a screencapture of a Outlook message with a custom message below the message Outlooks adds.

Comment: Would appending some text to the Subject meet your requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have found what you are after.

.FlagRequest is a free text field and it value is displayed in the same area as the "You replied on" message.

If you open the message and click `Flag` you can select one of the default message or enter your own.  You can only select one of the standard flag colours.

Alternatively: .FlagRequest, .FlagIcon, .FlagStatus and .FlagDueBy are read/write properties of a MailItem.

Comment: @ Jean-François Corbett. Thanks but good luck rather than good sleuthing. I have been playing with flags lately but did not link them with this question until I thought about where the follow-up message is displayed. I had assumed there was fixed list of messagesto select from. It was this question that caused me to investigate further.